Плохое соединение с сервером

Я  подключаюсь к серверу (на котором установена OC ubuntu) через TightVNC Viewer;
Подключение какое то время работает, но с большой задержкой (реакция на действия мыши происходит спустя сек где то);
Через несколько минут соединение прерывается со следующей ошибкой:


Подключение с другого компа, работает без проблем!
Как можно решить эту проблему?

пожалуйста, не добавляйте код/данные/текст ошибок картинками.

Банально плохой интернет, например?

инет хороший, обычные сайты позволяет просматривать, но при удалённом подключении возникает такая вот проблема

Обычные и на диалапе отлично просматриваются, а что насчёт необычных?

что подразумевается под необычными?

Ну например такие, которые жрут трафик так же сильно, как его жрёт VNC

Переходи на rdp. Производительность в разы лучше.
Реализация для x-server freerdp-shadow-cli - настроить примерно так https://stackoverflow.com/a/70879852/2101808
Для гнома и убунту есть реализация получше - gnome-remote-desktop - включается мышкой в настройках.
С 46 версии gnome-remote-desktop обещают поддержку headless.
Проблема vnc серверов и клиентов в том что они имеют нестандартные решения для ускоренного видео и не всегда сочетаются между собой.

Не. Для линукса есть проект x2go, весьма годная штука.

Рдп отзывчивее на данный момент. Там всякое AVC завезли.

X2go пробовал довольно давно. Но приложения саморендерящиеся (особенно фаерфокс) там работали весьма медленно.

Спасибо большое за совет! Попробую)
